# How to create Notification Setting page in android app using Onesignal Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, settings, android-notifications, onesignal

I want to create a Notification Setting page in android app, so that user can choose which type of notification they want. I'm using OneSignal push notification service and send notification form OneSignal Dashboard.

I've created group / categories in Onesignal Dashboard which is showing only android Oreo and later. That's why I want a Notification Setting Page inside app so that any version of android user can use this features.

I have only one java class for the one signal notification called ExampleApplication.java taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/Examples/AndroidStudio/app/src/main/java/com/onesignal/example/ExampleApplication.java).

```
package com.myapp.demo;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import com.onesignal.OSNotification;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationAction;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

        // Logging set to help debug issues, remove before releasing your app.

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler())
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
        OneSignal.enableVibrate(false);

    }


    private class ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
        @Override
        public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {

            JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
            String notificationID = notification.payload.notificationID;

            String customKey;
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "NotificationID received: " + notificationID);

            if (data != null) {
                customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
                if (customKey != null)
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

            String customKey;
            String openURL = null;
            Object activityToLaunch = MainActivity.class;

            if (data != null) {
                customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
                openURL = data.optString("openURL", null);

                if (customKey != null)
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);

                if (openURL != null)
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "openURL to webview with URL value: " + openURL);
            }

            if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken) {
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

                if (result.action.actionID.equals("id1")) {
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "button id called: " + result.action.actionID);
                    activityToLaunch = MainActivity.class;
                } else
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "button id called: " + result.action.actionID);
            }
            // The following can be used to open an Activity of your choice.
            // Replace - getApplicationContext() - with any Android Context.
            // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), (Class<?>) activityToLaunch);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // close app clearing all task
            //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            intent.putExtra("openURL", openURL);
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "openURL = " + openURL);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create setting page like this..

[image]

How can I create this notification setting page?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Settings.java

```
attendanceSwitch = findViewById(R.id.attendance_switch);
        noticeSwitch = findViewById(R.id.notice_switch);
        hwSwitch = findViewById(R.id.hw_switch);
        testSwitch = findViewById(R.id.test_switch);
        busSwitch = findViewById(R.id.bus_switch);
        settingsFeedback = findViewById(R.id.settings_feedback);

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("animate", false)){ reduceAnimation.setChecked(true); } else { reduceAnimation.setChecked(false); }

        reduceAnimation.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    editor.putBoolean("animate" , true);
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("animate" , false);
                }
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

////////////////
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("attendanceSwitch", true)){ attendanceSwitch.setChecked(true); } else { attendanceSwitch.setChecked(false); }

        attendanceSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    editor.putBoolean("attendanceSwitch" , true);
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("attendanceSwitch" , false);
                }
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
////////////////////////

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("noticeSwitch", true)){ noticeSwitch.setChecked(true); } else { noticeSwitch.setChecked(false); }

        noticeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    editor.putBoolean("noticeSwitch" , true);
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("noticeSwitch" , false);
                }
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
///////////////////////

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("hwSwitch", true)){ hwSwitch.setChecked(true); } else { hwSwitch.setChecked(false); }

        hwSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    editor.putBoolean("hwSwitch" , true);
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("hwSwitch" , false);
                }
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

//////////////////////////

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("testSwitch", true)){ testSwitch.setChecked(true); } else { testSwitch.setChecked(false); }

        testSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    editor.putBoolean("testSwitch" , true);
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("testSwitch" , false);
                }
                editor.apply();
            }
        });

 //////////////////////////

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("busSwitch", true)){ busSwitch.setChecked(true); } else { busSwitch.setChecked(false); }

        busSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    editor.putBoolean("busSwitch" , true);
                } else {
                    editor.putBoolean("busSwitch" , false);
                }
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
```

NotificationService.java

```
if (channelid.equals("Attendance")){

            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("attendanceSwitch", true)){

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelid);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo);
                builder.setContentTitle(title);
                builder.setContentText("Marked "+ attendance);
                builder.setPriority(pri);
                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
                notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

            }

        } else if (channelid.equals("test")){

            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("testSwitch", true)) {

                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        new Intent(this, PreQuiz.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelid);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo);
                builder.setContentTitle(title);
                builder.setContentText(body);
                builder.setPriority(pri);
                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
                notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

            }

        } else if (channelid.equals("notice")){

            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("noticeSwitch", true)) {


                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, Noticeboard.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            if (section.equals(sharedPreferences.getString("Section", "...")) || section.equals("All")) {
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelid);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo);
                builder.setContentTitle(title);
                builder.setContentText(body);
                builder.setPriority(pri);
                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                // builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp, "Sdad", snoozePendingIntent);
                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
                notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

            }
            }

        } else if (channelid.equals("hw")){

            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("hwSwitch", true)) {


                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        new Intent(this, Homework.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                if (section.equals(sharedPreferences.getString("Section", "...")) || section.equals("All")) {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelid);
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo);
                    builder.setContentTitle(title);
                    builder.setContentText(body);
                    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                    builder.setPriority(pri);
                    // builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp, "Sdad", snoozePendingIntent);
                    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
                    notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
                }
            }
```